# Open modal below navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Is there a way to open the modal under the navbar without the footer buttons disappearing?

I tried to use top, bottom and margin-top, but they push the modal down and the buttons disappear, is there any way to solve this problem?

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/ST7OEaE4V1)

**html**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal4">
Overflow
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel4" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-slideout modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal sideout small</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Explore the history of the classic Lorem Ipsum passage and generate your own text using any number of characters, words, sentences or paragraphs. Commonly used as placeholder text in the graphic and print industries, Lorem Ipsum's origins extend far back to a scrambled Latin passage from Cicero in the middle ages.</p>
       <p>Explore the history of the classic Lorem Ipsum passage and generate your own text using any number of characters, words, sentences or paragraphs. Commonly used as placeholder text in the graphic and print industries, Lorem Ipsum's origins extend far back to a scrambled Latin passage from Cicero in the middle ages.</p>
       <p>Explore the history of the classic Lorem Ipsum passage and generate your own text using any number of characters, words, sentences or paragraphs. Commonly used as placeholder text in the graphic and print industries, Lorem Ipsum's origins extend far back to a scrambled Latin passage from Cicero in the middle ages.</p>
       <p>Explore the history of the classic Lorem Ipsum passage and generate your own text using any number of characters, words, sentences or paragraphs. Commonly used as placeholder text in the graphic and print industries, Lorem Ipsum's origins extend far back to a scrambled Latin passage from Cicero in the middle ages.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.modal-dialog-slideout {min-height: 100%; margin: 0 0 0 auto;background: #fff;}
.modal.fade .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout {-webkit-transform: translate(100%,0)scale(1);transform: translate(100%,0)scale(1);}
.modal.fade.show .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout {-webkit-transform: translate(0,0);transform: translate(0,0);display: flex;align-items: stretch;-webkit-box-align: stretch;height: 100%;}
.modal.fade.show .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-slideout .modal-body{overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;}
.modal-dialog-slideout .modal-content{border: 0;}
.modal-dialog-slideout .modal-header, .modal-dialog-slideout .modal-footer {height: 69px; display: block;} 
.modal-dialog-slideout .modal-header h5 {float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to reduce the height of the element along with applying some margin-top.

Something like:

```
#exampleModal4 {
height: 90%;
display: block;
margin-top: 3%;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when inspecting the page, the modal changes in height, is not responsive :(

Comment: do you mean the scroll bar ?

Comment: Imagine that the modal (the header) is in the navbar line, when I inspect or reduce the screen, the modal almost goes to the middle of the navbar :(

Comment: Then you can try with calc the height like margin-top: 56px;
    height: calc(100% - 56px);